# Lost menu after installing classicmenu-indicator

Tags: 14.04, gnome, menu

I am running Ubuntu Gnome 14.04. I have gotten rid of the dash on the side and am using an application menu on the top bar by using Gnome extensions. I want to get the old style menu that I can edit it and rearrange items (extension menus, evidently, can't be edited or rearranged). So, in my stupidity, I installed `classicmenu-indicator`, which removed the menu extension from the top bar and made Gnome extensions "disappear" to the [extension listing on the Gnome extension site](https://extensions.gnome.org/local/). I have since removed the `classicmenu-indicator` but the extensions still don't show up listed on the site. I have used the Gnome Tweak tool to reinstate the menu extension but I want to 1] fix that part of Gnome that won't show up in the extensions page; 2] install the old classic menu. Keep in mind I didn't do a roll-back to get Gnome. This Ubuntu version has it already installed with the package.

Comment: The old-style `gnome` panel belongs to `gnome-panel` package , you can still get that.  I'm not quite sure what you refer to when you say "the menu extension from the top bar " . Would be nice if you could provide a screenshot

Comment: I have [Ubuntu *GNOME* 14.04][1]. With [GNOME extensions][2] I 'removed' Dash, etc. I'm using [an extension][3] which adds an "Applications" menu (http://leeunderwood.org/img/Screenshot-upper-left-menu-2016-07-17.png).

According to gnome-shell (v3.8.4), "The GNOME Shell is intended to replace functions handled by the GNOME Panel."

[1]: https://wiki.ubuntu.com/TrustyTahr/ReleaseNotes/UbuntuGNOME
[2]: https://extensions.gnome.org/
[3]: https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/6/applications-menu/

Comment: Well, when I turned-on the computer today, it seems to read the GNOME extensions properly. Guess problem [1] is fixed. Looks like I'll have to go elsewhere to fix problem [2].

Comment: New gnome shell indeed is intended to replace old gnome, but of you want thay old style panel you need `gnome-panel` package. or just switch to Ubuntu Mate

Comment: I'm not really picky. I just want to be able to edit the menus, something that doesn't seem possible using a Gnome extension.

Answer (score 1):

I installed Alacarte and it finally worked. Problem solved. Thanks for your help.